# Why doesn`t touchUp method trigger?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
table.setPosition(0, 0);
table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
table.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
table.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("me working");
        nextPhrase();
    }
});
stage.addActor(table);
```

The touchUp method doesn`t trigger. Table contains an Image and a Label and fills the screen. I need nextPhrase() method to trigger whenever screen is touched. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know libgdx but I read there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287866/libgdx-how-to-handle-touch-event) that you need an InputListener rather than a ClickListener (which would listen clicks, I believe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your full code but I assumed you have forgotten to update your `Stage`. If yes put this on your render/update method. What this do is to update all your `Actors` inside your Stage.

```
stage.act();
```

Also, don't forget to set your input processor to read input from the user.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have stage.act(), but I forgot to set InputProcessor.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Also, don't forget to accept an answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

the touchUp only gets triggered if the touchDown returns true. Otherwise the touch is no longer tracked.

I would however recommend implementing the "clicked" function in stead of the touchUp function, which handles this for you.