# libGDX what's the difference between InputListener, InputProcessor, InputAdapter

Tags: libgdx

I am a bit confused about touch handling of libGDX. I have seen the usage of all three types.

InputProcessor:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/24/LibGDX-Tutorial-5-Handling-Input-Touch-and-gestures.aspx

```
public class InputDemo2 implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {
    @Override
    public void create() {        
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    }
}
```

`InputListener` here:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx

```
    public MyActor(){
        setBounds(actorX,actorY,texture.getWidth(),texture.getHeight());
        addListener(new InputListener(){
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((MyActor)event.getTarget()).started = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

`InputAdapter` here:
[LibGdx, How to handle touch event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35287866/libgdx-how-to-handle-touch-event)

```
public class Prac1 extends ApplicationAdapter {
    @Override
    public void create () {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I don't find one different from another. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**InputListener**

`InputListener` is an `EventListener` for low-level input events that is provided for receiving and handling InputEvents.

`EventListener` is an interface with a `handle(Event)` method that are added to actors to be notified about events.  Classes that implement the `EventListener` interface use instanceof to determine whether they should handle the event.

An actor just needs to add an `InputListener` to start receiving input events.

---

**InputProcessor**

An `InputProcessor` is used to receive input events from the keyboard and the touch screen (mouse on the desktop). For this it has to be registered with the `Input.setInputProcessor(InputProcessor)` method. It will be called each frame before the call to `ApplicationListener.render()`.

**InputAdapter**

`InputAdapter` is just an adapter class for `InputProcessor`. If you want to override only some methods that you're interested in, use this class.